# Error: Access is denied. when calling asmx web service with .ajax()

Tags: ajax, json, web-services, sharepoint, asmx

I've just created a new Visual Studio 2012 solution for SharePoint 2013. I've crated an app for SP2013 and a .asmx web service. I want to call that web service from my app, but I always get `Error: Access is denied.`.

**My web service `.cs` code:**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class EmmaService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    } 
}
```

**My `.ajax()` call from app's javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:59054/EmmaService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(resp) {
                alert("success: " + resp);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                alert("error status: " + xhr.status);
                alert("error status text: " + xhr.statusText);
                alert("error response text: " + thrownError);
            },
        });
```

I saw people are getting the same error when calling a cross-domain web service, but my app and service is on the same domain, but I just can't access it, although I have all possible permissions everywhere (let's say I'm the only user on this server). Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, what can you suggest me to do then? I've tried creating a WCF service by this example: http://brianscodingexamples.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/creating-asp-net-c-wcf-web-service-in-visual-studio-2012/ , but in the end when I call that service in explorer I still get `The resource cannot be found.`

Comment: You need to find an example of creating and deploying a WCF service for SharePoint. General examples won't help you.

Comment: By the way, you are just pulling the data from the webservice, so use GET instead and make the required changes to the web.config file that allows you to use asmx service in GET mode.. :)

Comment: I've done that, still had no success, now I'm trying with WCF service though :)